# how do I match the data and return same data of first array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, sorting

I have two array

```
arr1 =[{name:'Net Banking', id:'NetBanking'},{name:'Debit Card', id:'DebitCard'},{name:'Credit Card', id:'CreditCard'}]
```

and

```
arr2=['DebitCard','NetBanking']
```

and I want to expected result as of arr1

```
arr1=[{name:'Debit Card', id:'DebitCard'}, {name:'Net Banking', id:'NetBanking'}]
```

currently I am using -

```
arr1.filter(data=>arr2.includes(data.id))
```

and I am getting return as

```
arr1 =[{name:'Net Banking', id:'NetBanking'},{name:'Debit Card', id:'DebitCard'}]
```

means match the element of arr2 with arr1 and return as arr1 with same order of arr2

or how can I change the index based on arr2 of arr1

Comment: The filtering works. Now the order is a different problem altogether. After your filtering is done, you have to perform additional logic so the filtered array is in the same order as `arr2`. Or you can do `const arr3 = arr2.map( name => arr1.find( obj => obj.id===name  ))`

Comment: There are good answers below. Why have you not marked one as accepted? Is there something wrong with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the desired input.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const arr1 =[{name:'Net Banking', id:'NetBanking'},{name:'Debit Card', id:'DebitCard'},{name:'Credit Card', id:'CreditCard'}];

const arr2=['DebitCard','NetBanking'];

const resArray = arr2.map((item) => arr1.find((obj) => obj.id === item));

console.log(resArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through `arr2` and for each item find the related object with the same `id` in array `arr1`

You can rely on

1. [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
2. [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let arr1 =[{name:'Net Banking', id:'NetBanking'},{name:'Debit Card', id:'DebitCard'},{name:'Credit Card', id:'CreditCard'}];

let arr2=['DebitCard','NetBanking'];

const result = arr2.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
   /*
   * For the current item of the loop search for item with
   * object.id === current
   */
   return accumulator.concat(arr1.find(item => item.id === current));
},[]);

console.log(result);
```